# Please explain what happened to Abbott at the end of Arrival

Tags: analysis, arrival

Almost at the end of the movie when Louise voluntarily goes to the shell and she meets Costello and asks about Abbott..and as a response Costello says

> that Abbot is in a death process.

I was wondering if anyone knew more about this, **if it was a natural process**.

[image: Last Scene with Louise in the shell]

Answer (score 10):

### No, it was not natural.

Abbott was

> mortally injured when the bomb planted by some rogue members of the American military who were trying to blow up the alien's ship went off.

Because the aliens perceive time in a non-linear fashion, pretty much everything is a "process"